# Dynamics 365 Data Migration using Azure Data Factory

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, azure-data-factory, dynamics-365

I want to export my the listmember entity's data to the Azure SQL Database.
I wrote a fetch XML query and it worked.

```
<fetch>
<entity name="list">
<attribute name="listname" />
<attribute name="listid" alias="List" />
<link-entity name="listmember" from="listid" to="listid" intersect="true">
<attribute name="entitytype" />
<attribute name="listmemberid" />
<attribute name="entityid" />
</link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

The list that I try to export has over 100K records.
But Fetch XML returns only the first 5K and ADF insert only this 5K.

How can I export all ListMember data?

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this instead of the Export To Data Lake feature that is built in to Dynamics?

Comment: yes. I have to export specific lists to another product's DB. The other product can't read the data from any other place.

Comment: Whilst the other product can't read from other places, Data Factory can.  If you configure the Entity from within Dynamics to export to a Data Lake, you can then query the Data Lake using Data Factory and load the data you require into the destination database.

Comment: Thank you @iamdave, It is a solution but not the optimal one. I need to execute two different processes based on yours suggestion. Also, it will increase my process time. I'm looking for how can I execute fetch XML page by page in ADF?

Comment: Once configured, the Export To Data Lake is a continuous, real-time update that is automatically managed by Dynamics, so the data in the Data Lake is always current and you don't need to repeatedly execute anything on that side.  You would just be executing a single ADF pipeline that copies data from the Data Lake to the SQL Db instead of from a FetchXML query to the SQL Db; the complexity is essentially the same.  Read up on the Dataverse, why Microsoft is pushing it and what you can do with it.  It is the future of Dynamics data extraction.

Comment: I got it. But when ADF supports fetch XML I want to use it. But what will happen if fetch XML returns over 5000 records? I think Microsoft has to think about it and share documents for this.

Comment: *But when ADF supports fetch XML I want to use it* - Why?  It clearly has a limitation [(That I don't think you can actually work around)](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/275989/how-to-get-more-than-5000-records-using-fetchxml-query) that will require you to execute several queries instead of a single bulk load.  ADF also supports reading Dataverse data from a Data Lake, without that limitation, with standard built in connectors and is the recommended way to pull data out of Dynamics.

Comment: Thank you, Dave. 1 last question. It is ok for static lists but what about dynamic lists? I have to execute the query belong dynamics list to get the members. Because dynamics list members will not exist in the ListMember entity.

Comment: As I said, it is a real-time update of the data as it is in your Dynamics Entities.  If you change any of the data in the system, it will automatically update in the Data Lake.  So yes, both static and dynamic lists will be available and up to date, provided you have configured them to be included in the Export To Data Lake.

Comment: members of dynamics lists does not exist in any entity!

Comment: They will be included in the Entity Metada json file that is exported along with the Entity.

Comment: Unless you are referring to Marketing Lists...?

Comment: I'm referring to Marketing Lists:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to have a parameter/variable in pipeline with array type. Array should contain two values one to indicate take first 5000 rows and second to indicate another set of 5000 rows. Use ForEach activity on top of it to loop through them and inside Foreach use Copy activity with dynamic query to take rows accordingly and load in to Sink.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've already tried it but when I add to the specific page number to fetch XML it gives an error. The error is:  Should not specify paging related attributes in your Fetch XML query